# How Should I Design my Medival Fantasy Fortress?

Tags: magic, military-defense, strategy

My name is Austin

I am a writer trying to design the concept of a "perfect fortress" that can viably defend against all kinds of adversaries. However, I am in need of suggestions to improve the concept design. Before I go in to the details, I want to note that the time period is during the very early development of firearms and cannons, so they are utilized, but aren't common yet. This period is also set in a fantasy setting, where magic (like pyromancy)and fantasy creatures (like dragons) exist. However, the magic factor should be ignored, because it is a topic all on its own.

Stronghold name: The Morning Star

Brief description: Standing between the intersectional borders of four Neutral Nations, the Morning star it an 8 pointed Star Fort, which is a center of international trade, political discourse and a temporary sanctuary for asylum seekers.

This Fortress is built around a Bountiful Spring that outflows into the four rivers that run into the nations it stands between. listed below are the potential dangers it may face, along with possible solutions:

1.Land Assaults. Solution: Moats, Good Engineering, Loopholes, Machiculations, ect.

2.Air Assaults (Dragons, arial deployment, Bombardments). Solutions: Not sure, (need help)

3.Prolonged Siege. Solutions: Limited defenders, Large food stores, Secure Freshwater.

4.Natural Disasters (like earthquakes, fires or hurricanes) Solution: Good Foundational engeineering, including fireproof designs.

5.Biological Warfare Solution: Not sure, (need help)

6.Internal threats (traitors or Coercion) Solution: also, sot sure (need help)

While it is true that there is no such thing as a "Perfect Fortress", I am trying to learn about the qualities that make other fortresses strong so I may implement them into one of my own.

I gratefully welcome input on all of these Threats that this  Fort may face, not just the Threats that I have no solutions for.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  SE's Q&A model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).  And you should remember the words of General Patton, "Fixed fortifications are a monument to the stupidity of man."  The best defense truly is a good offense. Cut off supplies and wait = fort dies.

Comment: Finally, please note that the purpose for voting to close a question (and closing a question) is to give you time to improve your question before spurious answers begin to appear.  It isn't a judgment, it's an opportunity.  You may want to consider using our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168) to improve your question.

Comment: Star forts were a new innovation in the days of firearms, but they were never designed to withstand aerial assault.

Comment: No such thing as a 'perfect' fortress. Open spaces for catapults and arbalests mean more manpower (who must be fed) needed to defend longer walls...and are also perfect landing zones for the enemy's avian dragoons. Everything is a tradeoff. The best defense saps the enemy's strengths (whatever they are) and protects the friendly's weaknesses (whatever they are). Example: All of Saurons armies and mighty fortifications availed him nothing. Minas Tirith was a vast *fortress city* for thousands of years...yet nearly fell in a couple days.

Comment: I'd edit the question and make two, at least; aside for the aforementioned points, someone once said that "a wall is just good as the men protecting it". This meaning that defence agains treachery, mind control magic, defection, disertion, biological warfare and even starvation are more related too logistic and adequate troop training and discipline rather than architecture design. No fortress can prevent a soldier from betraying you, but a good sistem of stick and carrots can!

Comment: I voted to close as this question is too broad.  Attempting to even enumerate 'any other threats in a fantasy setting' would take too long.  Defending against just the psychological threats is a question all its own.  Defending against all threats is just too broad to be answered.

Comment: Another thing that makes this question to broad is the introduction of "magic" and "fantasy creatures". We don't know what magic can and can not do in your universe. And we don't know what kind of fantasy creatures there are in your world and what abilities they have. Do you need a fortress which can defend against teleporting imps? Or giants which are literally the size of a mountain? [Sentient clouds of poison gas](https://oots.fandom.com/wiki/Chlorine_Elemental)? Time travelers who kill the architect of your fortress as a baby?

Comment: *"Internal threats, like treachery or mind control"*. Keep the keep empty.

Comment: @Austin Trigloff You might want to see answers to this question: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/127177/build-an-impregnable-fortress-in-the-middle-ages-with-modern-technology/127259#127259

Comment: On hold but, you basically want this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citadel_Hill_(Fort_George) It has a lot of defensive features for different bombardment.  To defend against cannons, it provides nothing to hit because it is in the ground, to protect against ground assaults, it has outer walls full of rifle holes to rip through any invaders and they enter the pit.  It has natural cold storage being low down.  It's on a hill to slow advance and give great cannon range at ships attacking.  It's about as perfect as you can get.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I will work on modifying the question to narrow down the challenges i'm trying to tackle.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically impossible to design a perfect fortress. There's always going to be some way to breach the walls or starve out the defenders. So, with that in mind, we'll see how close we can get to what you have in mind.

1. Land assaults should be pretty easy to defend against. The star shaped dirt you're talking about is apready designed to repel cannon fire and infantry assaults, so you're already prepared for that. To make it a little harder, dig a mote and other earthworks around it, and put it in a hard to reach area, like a dense forest, or a swamp. Aerial assaults are something a bit harder to defend against, and it really depends what kind of aerial vehicles or creatures will be attacking. If dragons are the main problem, simply cover all your buildings with thick stone. Expensive, but it should protect against fire. Alternatively, you could just keep your courtyard bare, and have all the barracks and such inside the already stone walls.
2. There's really only one solution to a siege. Make sure you have access to food and water. For the water, make sure you have a deep well inside your fortress. As far as food is concerned, you either have to store it up, or grow it. So, either invent really efficient farming techniques, or have really big storehouses.
3. The danger of earthquakes can be mitigated by implementing construction similar to those used in Japanese castles. Basically, by using a slanted base and careful construction of layered stones, they managed to absorb the shock of earthquakes. For windstorms, I would make sure that all your buildings are of sturdy construction, or built into the sturdy walls of the fort.
4. Treachery can only be prevented by using loyal troops and officers, and practicing good leadership. If you have the respect and loyalty of your men, then treachery isn't an issue. Mind control can only be prevented by some other fantasy element like magic or charms.
5. Biological warfare is tricky. One thing is to prevent water contamination by ensuring your well is clean and impossible to poison by your enemy. You could also institute mandatory hand washing, or have everyone wear scarves over their mouths and noses to prevent the spread of disease. Basically, this comes down to practicing sanitary behavior, like separating the sick and the healthy, and providing healthy food to your defenders.
6. Sorry, but there's nothing I can do here.

Comment: The star castle won't last too long against heavy cannon bombardment.  For that, you'd need lots and lots of dirt, like a Vauban-era star fort.  It also looks wide open to air attack.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I'm going to remodel the post to follow the appropiate guidelines along with taking into consideration the suggestions i've already recieved. Thank you.